# For how long are the sessions valid when the browser is closed?

Tags: php, security, session, cookies

When we use `session.cookie_lifetime = 0` in PHP, the cookie will be deleted by the browser when it's closed. But the server has no way to know about this, so it relies on the fact that the cookie won't be used again.

What I want to know is for how long is the session valid on the server side, in case someone recovers that cookie.

Comment: session life can be set when created or it uses the default for your php. phpinfo() will tell you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a Debian Linux system there is a cron job which cleans the "dead" sessions.

The max lifetime is in your php.ini file

`/etc/cron.d/php5`: crontab fragment for php5

This purges session files older than X, where X is defined in seconds
as the largest value of session.gc_maxlifetime from all your php.ini
files, or 24 minutes if not defined. See `/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime`.

Look for and purge old sessions every 30 minutes:

```
09,39 *     * * *     root   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) -delete
```